# Specifying the template parameter for lambda in C++20

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

I am implementing some kind of a visit on my class where users will provide polymorphic lambda and I will do dispatching based on runtime index.
Simple silly example is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/yxwL5H):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename F>
void visit(F f){
    if(rand()%2){
        f(47);
    } else {
        f(4.7);
    }
}

int main()
{
    visit([]<typename T>(const T& ){std::cout << sizeof(T);});
    visit([]<typename T>(const T& ){std::cout << sizeof(T);});
    visit([]<typename T>(const T& ){std::cout << sizeof(T);});
    visit([]<typename T>(const T& ){std::cout << sizeof(T);});
    visit([]<typename T>(const T& ){std::cout << sizeof(T);});
    visit([]<typename T>(const T& ){std::cout << sizeof(T);});
    visit([]<typename T>(const T& ){std::cout << sizeof(T);});
};
```

This works but if lambda only cares about the type of argument and not it's value it requires lambda to take 1 useless argument.

Is there a way I could rewrite this code so that I tell lambda what T it is being called with, and having callback arity 0?

Obvious attempt (`f<int>, f<double>`) does not work.

This works but it is quite ugly, is there a nicer way?

```
void visit(F f){
    if(rand()%2){
        f.template operator()<int>();
    } else {
        f.template operator()<double>();
    }
}
```